# GWT: add custom locations to the list of autcomplete results

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I am trying to add a list of strings to the autocomplete values returned to the autcomplete Text bar
when these values are selected i must process them locally before retrieving information from the google servers.

this is the code which binds the AutoComplete entity to the auto text field.

```
final AutoCompleteOptions options = new AutoCompleteOptions();
options.setTypes(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "geocode" }));
final AutoComplete autoComplete = new AutoComplete(this.auto.getElement(), options);
autoComplete.bindTo("bounds", (com.google.gwt.maps.client.Map) this.mapWidget.getMap());
```

Any ideas?